# Symfony2 + Doctrine2 onDelete="restrict"

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I want to restrict a delete action on my object, but it's not working.

My code from my first entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Season", inversedBy="clubs")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="clubs_to_seasons",
 *     joinColumns={
 *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="club_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
 *     },
 *     inverseJoinColumns={
 *         @ORM\JoinColumn(name="season_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="restrict")
 *     }     
 * )
 **/
private $seasons;
```

And second:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="League")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="validation.custom.not_blank")
 */
 private $league;
```

On database side everything is fine - I cannot delete a Season object, because it has a reference to Club object, but when I use a remove fuction from Entity Manager, Season object is deleted.

I know that on ORM side is a `cascade={..}` but I need a restrict, not cascade.

BUMP:

If I'm using one-to-many, many-to-one or one-to-one, everything is ok - when I try to delete an object (and I'm using `onDelete="restrict"` on the database side), then exceptions appears with message, that I cannot delete because I have other object connected with. But when I have many-to-many (as in my example), and I have a season associated with any club (and I have onDelete="restrict"), still I can delete a season using entity manager. But when I'm deleting season directly on the db side, message appears, and I cannot delete this.

What is wrong with many-to-many?

EDIT:
OK, now it's working.

My solution for the future:
I removed many-to-many relation from both entities. I have made a third entity - clubToSeason. Previously this entity was autogenerated, now it's not. And inside file of this third entity I have two many-to-one relations:

```
class ClubToSeason {

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="season", inversedBy="clubs")
   **/
  private $season;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="club", inversedBy="seasons")
   **/
  private $club;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Any ideas, how I can create onDelete="restrict" on ORM side?

Comment: BUMP. I added my solution.